# npm scoped packages and powershell

Tags: powershell, npm

I would like to install new [angular2-material](https://github.com/angular/material2) npm packages  but it seems to be a scoped package and I don't know how to manage that under windows. @ Symbol seems to be problematic with powershell.

```
npm install --save @angular2-material/{core} 

Unrecognized token in source text.
    At line:1 char:20
    + npm install --save  <<<< @angular2-material/{core}
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnrecognizedToken
```

Have someone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found..
It needs **Powershell 3.0** to be able to use @-symbol for scoped packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't or don't want to update to Powershell 3.0+, you can use the backtick character (`) to escape the @ symbol:

`` npm install `@angular2-material/{core} ``